# LButton-scroll registers as Ctrl-scroll if VCL control has a child control

Tags: windows, delphi, zooming, mousewheel, window-messages

It seems like a windowed VCL control registers LButton-scroll as Ctrl-scroll if the window has a windowed child control. At least this happens if the user is using a Logitech MX Master mouse.

Consider the following minimal example:

```pascal
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Label1: TLabel;
    procedure FormMouseWheelDown(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
      MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
    procedure FormMouseWheelUp(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
      MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
  private
    procedure ZoomIn;
    procedure ZoomOut;
  public
  end;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormMouseWheelDown(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if ssCtrl in Shift then
    ZoomOut;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseWheelUp(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if ssCtrl in Shift then
    ZoomIn;
end;

procedure TForm1.ZoomIn;
begin
  Font.Size := Font.Size + 1;
end;

procedure TForm1.ZoomOut;
begin
  if Font.Size >= 6 then
    Font.Size := Font.Size - 1;
end;

end.
```

This allows me to zoom using Ctrl+wheel:

[image: Screen recording of a zooming label.]

Now, let's add a button to the form:

[image: Screenshot of form with a button.]

I can still zoom using Ctrl+wheel, but now the form is also zoom if I scroll the mouse wheel while having the left mouse button depressed:

[image: Screen recording of zooming label]

This is very annoying. Is there a known workaround for this?

Comment: So far, I have replicated the same problem in both 10.3 and 2009, but only using Logitech mice.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious solution is simply not to use the apparently unreliable `Shift` parameter:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormMouseWheelDown(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) < 0 then
    ZoomOut;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormMouseWheelUp(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  MousePos: TPoint; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  if GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) < 0 then
    ZoomIn;
end;
```

Comment: I would blame the mouse driver before blaming the VCL. The VCL is simply translating the information that Windows reports in `WM_LBUTTON...` and `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` messages.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I also think the problem is the mouse driver. But from my perspective, that doesn't change the fact that I cannot rely on the `Shift` parameter.

Comment: In addition, this is very much not an uncommon mouse driver, so if this indeed happens to every user having that driver, I think it makes sense to use the above workaround unconditionally.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Don't blame driver. I can reproduce this scenario on my computer both with Logitech Wireless mouse as well as with Logitech wired mouse. Now after some more testing I find out that this is happening if the form contains any focusable control like `Button`, `Memo`, `ListBox`, `EditBox` etc. But as soon as you disable `TabSto`p property for these components problem goes away. So I'm guessing the cause might lie somewhere in Tab shifting code.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Another interesting thing is that when form contains focusable button moving mouse scroll fires `FormMouseWheelDown` three times. In first two times `Shift` is `ssLeft` in last `Shift` is `ssCtrl`. If there is no focusable button on the form `FormMouseWheelDown` fires only once as it should.

Comment: Correction this problem occurs whenever there is any focused control on the form even if at design time the control TabStop property was disabled.

Comment: @SilverWarior: Thank you for confirming that this issue doesn't only happen on my machines.

Comment: Which Delphi version(s) is this happening in?

Comment: @RemyLebeau: In my case it is 10.3 (update 2, 26.0.34749.6593). I also tried it in Delphi 2009, and the same problem happens there.

Comment: @RemyLebeau In my case it is also in Delphi 10.3. I currently don't have any other versions installed to test this in them.

Comment: The `OnMouseWheel...` events are triggered only in response to `WM_MOUSEWHEEL` messages from the OS. The `Shift` parameter is a direct translation of the message's `WParam` flags. So, if the `ssCtrl` flag is present, that is simply the way the OS reported it. So the problem is in the OS, not the VCL. Which goes back to the likely culprit being a faulty driver, especially if the problem is reproducible only for Logitech mice and not other manufacturers.